# Esiste una traduzione informale della parola inglese "trope"?

Tags: translation

Sto cercando di trovare una traduzione per il termine inglese "trope", nel suo significato di "pattern in storytelling".

Fino ad ora, le uniche traduzioni che ho trovato sono "tropo" e "figura retorica", ma la prima è una parola poco comune, ed entrambe hanno un tono formale, la seconda quasi accademico.

Esiste una traduzione meno formale, da poter usare (per esempio) mentre si parla di serie TV con degli amici?

Comment: “Tropo” e “figura retorica”, più che altro, non sono lo stesso che _trope_ in inglese. Io e qualcuno che conosco usiamo “[topos](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/topos)”, anche parlando di serie TV, ma forse siamo solo noi.

Comment: In alternativa c'è “motivo” (che è sia una parola comune che un termine tecnico: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif-Index_of_Folk-Literature) o più in generale qualcosa come “tema” (il tema del riscatto, della vendetta). Con amici – ma questo è veramente un nostro lessico famigliare – parliamo anche di “vecchio trucco” (il vecchio trucco del gemello, del fuso orario etc.).

Comment: Si potrebbe usare anche l'espressione "motivo ricorrente" o, anche se entrambi i termini sono presi in prestito da altre lingue, "*leitmotiv*" o "*cliché*"

Comment: @secan: Sono spunti interessanti, ma non sono sicuro che colgano il senso di “pattern in storytelling”. In particolare, “cliché” ha una connotazione molto negativa: “Espressione priva di originalità, spesso ripetuta, e perciò fastidiosa; frase fatta, stereotipata, abusata” etc. (Treccani).

Comment: @DaG, premetto che non conoscevo il termine *trope*, quindi ne ho cercato il significato. Ho indicato "cliché" perché il [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trope) lo indica come sinonimo di *trope*, nel significato di "*a common or **overused** theme or device*" (assegnadogli quindi la stessa sfumatura negativa). Il [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/trope) invece ne da una definizione più neutra di "*a recurring theme or idea*". P.S. Anch'io, personalmente, uso spesso "*topos*" ma non direi che si tratti di un termine informale e comune

Comment: Anche “ filo conduttore”  viene usato in questo senso 


“*elemento, struttura logica che costituisce la base di un ragionamento, un discorso, ecc. o intorno a cui si articola un racconto, una narrazione e sim.: un romanzo privo di un filo conduttore*”  DeMauro

Comment: Ora che ci penso, oltre che "*motivo/tema/immagine **ricorrente***", si usa frequentemente anche il termine "*classico*"; ad esempio "il *tema* della casa infestata è un **classico** del cinema horror" e, parlando di un autore, in determinati casi si potrebbe anche usare l'espressione "*marchio di fabbrica*" ("gli zombie sono il marchio di fabbrica di George Romero")

Comment: Ho l'impressione, forse erronea, che stiamo facendo un po' di confusione tra singoli elementi di una trama considerati da un punto di vista “neutro” (un intoppo lungo la strada del protagonista), trame viste nel loro complesso (il viaggio dell'eroe), cliché nel senso negativo di elemento banale (la maglietta rossa morirà) e forse qualcos'altro. Credo che l'OP abbia in mente soprattutto il tipo di concetti raccolti per es. in https://tvtropes.org/. OP, potresti forse fare qualche esempio per chiarire il concetto che vuoi esprimere?

Comment: @DaG Esatto, sto cercando una parola italiana che abbia lo stesso significato di "trope" per come viene usato in tvtropes; quindi più o meno che esprima il concetto generico di "quella cosa ricorrente in certi film/libri/ecc."

Comment: @ThePirate42, in questo caso, credo che per rimanere nell'ambito della discussione informale, possa andare "tema (o anche tematica, situazione, scena) ricorrente (o classico/a)". Anche "motivo ricorrente", come suggeriva DaG, potrebbe andare anche se, parlando di film e TV, c'è un *minimo* rischio che, a seconda del contesto, possa essere erroneamente interpretto come "motivo musicale" (quindi la colonna sonora di un film o un jingle pubblicitario).